# template template parameters with boost::fast_pool_allocator

Tags: c++, templates, boost

Why doesn't this compile:

```
std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, boost::fast_pool_allocator< std::pair< int, int > > a_Test;
```

but this compiles fine:

```
typedef boost::fast_pool_allocator< std::pair< int, int > > fast_alloc;
std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, fast_alloc > a_Test;
```

A separate question: as far as I can see in the definition of `boost::fast_pool_allocator` it takes four non-defaulted template parameters, but in the example above it works fine. Can anyone please explain the reason for this? Thanks!

Comment: In the first version, you forgot a `>` at the end

Comment: What ar you compilation error ? Can you add it to your question ?

Comment: @Antonio was right, sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition should read

```
std::map<
  int,
  int,
  std::less<int>,
  boost::fast_pool_allocator<
    std::pair< int, int >
  >
> a_Test;
```

You should always format longer template instantiations with its parameters on separate lines. That way you cannot miss closing brackets.

`boost::fast_pool_allocator` is forward-declared with default template parameters in `poolfwd.hpp`.

Just to clarify the naming conventions: The allocator parameter is not a template template parameter here since you fully specify it by setting its type to `std::pair<int, int>`.